# iPad touchstart firing twice

Tags: javascript, ipad

I am working on cross platform touch events. (swiping etc) They work on Android devices but for iPad the touchstart event is firing twice.

```
this.element.addEventListener('touchstart', mousedown, false);

var mousedown = function(event) {
    // Finger Press
    event.preventDefault();
    _this.inGesture = true;
    _this._originalX = (event.touches) ? event.touches[0].pageX : event.pageX;
    _this._originalY = (event.touches) ? event.touches[0].pageY : event.pageY;

};
```

This function is firing twice on iPad, but functioning correctly on Android.

I should add that it fires touchstart, then touchmove, then touchend and finally it does another touchstart for some reason.

Here it is on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Lb3Z/1

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQqce.png

Comment: I just tested on my iPad and it fires once -- http://jsfiddle.net/Kai/N7NA5/

Comment: Okay thanks for that, the problem must be somewhere else. Here it is on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Lb3Z/

Comment: I updated the fiddle to run correctly on jsfiddle; I still see only one touchstart call: http://www.jsfiddle.net/6Lb3Z/1/  I'm using an iPad2 with iOS 5.1. Screenshot http://i.imgur.com/Oz5z4.png

Comment: I just tested it on two different iPhones and a iPad2 on iOS 5.1 andit works correctly on them. It's just on this iPad2 on 4.3.2

Think I may just ignore it for now!

Comment: Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/GS8uI.png

Comment: Since it's specific to 4.3.2, it might have been a bug they fixed in a later release. I couldn't find anything on Google about it, though. Can you confirm you're not including/calling anything twice that might register the event handler a second time in some other part of your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a library like jQuery or Zepto, then you could use the `.one` method.

From the [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/one/) of jQuery:

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed
>   at most once per element.

Comment: Isn't that once ever - rather than only once per touch?